# Invalid initial heap size

Tags: java, docker, apache-spark

This is the log of the error message I get when I deploy a spark job on an EKS cluster.
Using Spark 2.4.2 embedded into a Docker image Alpine 3.9.

Do you have any idea about it?

Thanks

```
++ id -u
+ myuid=0
++ id -g
+ mygid=0
++ getent passwd 0
+ uidentry=root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/ash
+ '[' -z root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/ash ']'
+ SPARK_K8S_CMD=driver
+ '[' -z driver ']'
+ shift 1
+ SPARK_CLASSPATH=':/opt/spark/jars/*'
+ env
+ grep SPARK_JAVA_OPT_
+ sort -t_ -k4 -n
+ sed 's/[^=]*=\(.*\)/\1/g'
+ readarray -t SPARK_JAVA_OPTS
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ case "$SPARK_K8S_CMD" in
+ CMD=(${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java "${SPARK_JAVA_OPTS[@]}" -cp "$SPARK_CLASSPATH" -Xms$SPARK_DRIVER_MEMORY -Xmx$SPARK_DRIVER_MEMORY -Dspark.driver.bindAddress=$SPARK_DRIVER_BIND_ADDRESS $SPARK_DRIVER_CLASS $SPARK_DRIVER_ARGS)
+ exec /sbin/tini -s -- /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/bin/java -cp ':/opt/spark/jars/*' -Xms -Xmx -Dspark.driver.bindAddress=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Invalid initial heap size: -Xms
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Comment: Well `-Xms` and `-Xmx` need values, e.g. `-Xms64m` or `-Xmx256g`

Comment: You have to increase your heap size.if there is any configuration which gives -Xms and -Xmx value then you have to provide the size value and if you have already provided then its not that much enough so have to increase as well.

Comment: Indeed I tried to add something like: ENV JAVA_OPTS="-XX:PermSize=1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m" but it didn't' work. Trying to find a workaround

Comment: Thanks everyone, it was an issue related to the entry point and an hidden library used in a base image.